# Using negative look behind while still returning the matching subexpression

Tags: c#, .net, regex, lookbehind

So I can use negative look-behind to search for all occurrances of the string `<ANYTHING>.dbo.TableName` where `<ANYTHING>` is not some particular string. The problem is that the returned matches do not catch the value of `<ANYTHING>` subexpression. For exmaple, if I have the following text:

```
Test1.dbo.MyTable
Test2.dbo.MyTable
Test123.dbo.MyTable
Test223.dbo.MyTable
```

and I use the following regex:

```
(?<!Test1)\.dbo\.MyTable
```

It does catch all the occurrences except the first one, but the matches only contain `.dbo.MyTable` and not the preceding value that has been ignored by the negative look-behind. How can I catch the missing part?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could precede your lookbehind with `\w` to match word characters in order to match the entire substring.

```
\w+(?<!Test1)\.dbo\.MyTable
```

[**Explanation**](http://regexdoc.com/re/explain.pl?re=%5Cw%2B%28%3F%3C%21Test1%29%5C.dbo%5C.MyTable&.submit=Explain%21&mode=SO&.cgifields=mode) | [**Live Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/lR6zZ2/4)

Comment: OMG. Can't believe I missed that. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

Either change your regex to use a negative lookahead:

```
^(?!Test1)\w+\.dbo\.
```

Or use a positive lookbehind with a capture (this will be a variable-length lookbehind, which .NET supports):

```
(?<!Test1)(?<=(\w+))\.dbo\.
```

The first way is cleaner IMO.